# Bash script to start Docker containers

Tags: linux, bash, docker

This script works:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..10}
    do echo “yes $i”
done
```

But when attempting to start several Docker containers it only starts the first container and exits:

**docker_run.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..10}
    do exec docker run —name docker-nginx$i -P -d nginx
    sleep 3
done
```

The `sleep 3` was added to give it time. Not sure if it matters. Of course the script has to run with `sudo` permissions.

Comment: Why do you use `exec` command? Try to do it running directly `docker`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run many docker machines your script should be  like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..10}
    do docker run —name docker-nginx$i -P -d nginx
    sleep 3
done
```

You should not use `exec` in this case as `exec` *replaces* the current process (your script) with the process resulting from executing its arguments (`docker ...`).  This is why your script never gets past the first iteration.